# amazon ads not showing up on media query css

Tags: javascript, html, css, amazon-web-services, media-queries

I've created a fluid design website, that has 3 columns and one of the columns has amazon affiliate ads.  Those ads are images that contains links.  I made javascript so the images will be fluid - when users change the browser window size, those ads images will shrink or enlarge. That works perfectly when I had only one CSS file, but now I have multiple CSS files for different screen sizes.  When the website is using media screen CSS files, the images do not show up at all.  The codes are below - Please help!

/*class for amazon ads image */

```
ul li .coverImg{

    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    position:relative;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    overflow:hidden;

    }

/*javascript allAmazonImgs are called by class .coverImg*/

var allAmazonImgs = document.getElementsByClassName("coverImg");     
var allAmazonImgsAspectRatio = new Array(); 
var iImgIndex = 0; 

    for(i=0;i < allAmazonImgs.length;i++)
    {

    var oImg = allAmazonImgs[i];
    allAmazonImgsAspectRatio[iImgIndex] = parseInt(oImg.offsetHeight/oImg.offsetWidth);
    iImgIndex++;

    }
```

My website uses PHP - HTML is calling the row value from mySQL. " />

Comment: I think I'll need to see your HTML - the links that load the CSS files. There may be something wrong with how they are called, or the CSS files may interfere with each other.

Comment: Also, what is the relationship between iImgIndex and i? Why are they not the same?

Comment: Hi Mr.Lister!  Thank you for the comment.  My website uses PHP - HTML is calling the row value from mySQL.  <img class="coverImg" border="0" src="<?php echo($row["ImageSourceURL"]); ?>" />

Comment: I forgot to paste the variables for javascript. Here's what they are.   var allAmazonImgs = document.getElementsByClassName("coverImg");     var allAmazonImgsAspectRatio = new Array();
var iImgIndex = 0;

Comment: You should edit your post and put that in. But this Javascript hasn't changed since adding the extra files?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm new to this.  Didn't know how I could edit the original post.  Now they are there.  No, the file hasn't changed.

Comment: Problem resolved.  Thank you Mr. Lister, I didn't realize, but there was a mistake in a function of a different area.  Thank you for looking into for me!